# How to store the web response in global.asax so that i can use this response from my wcf rest service using C#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, global-asax

I am trying to create this global.aspx for my project where i have created

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
         var jsoniff = String.Empty;
        string fileName = www.abcd/xyc.com
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileName);
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        jsoniff = reader.ReadToEnd();

    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown

    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started

    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

    }

</script>
```

now when ever i make a new build or restart this project this global.asax would be executed. 
In the above script i have added a Application_Start which includes called a URl and reading the JSON response to end. Now i need to use this jsoniff in my WCF REST service.
How do i need to call jsoniff in my REST service and is the above implementation correct or not.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use AJAX? That will be more preferred for client side programming.

Comment: I wish I could. Currently i am restricted to use only global.asax .
So i need to go ahead with the above methodology